# Why this ternary operator are not working ? is not ternary operator are functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just learned about the ternary operator but it is not functioning like I expected. If find it really confusing. I get an error in the console over and over again, and I don't understand why.

A normal function gives me undefined, which is fine, but the ternary operator gives me a "not defined" error, but why?

Ternary Operator

```
var experiencePoints = winBattle() ? 10 : 1;
```

Error

> VM363:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: winBattle is not defined

My function

```
function experiencePoints() {
    if (winBattle()) {
        return 10;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And it gives:

```
undefined
```

I want to get undefined just like the normal function gives.

Comment: where is `winBattle` declared? did you call `experiencePoints`?

Comment: have you anywhere declared a `function winBattle()`? If not, then that is the reason for your error. It is not related directly to use of the ternary operator.

Comment: If you call `experiencePoints()` what happens?

Comment: The error means that `winBattle` doesn't exist in the scope you are trying to access it from. Not much we can do help besides pointing that out. If you'd post a complete example that includes the declaration of `winBattle` we may be able to tell were you went wrong.

Comment: you have a error because the  function winBattle is not defined, as your system say, not because you use ternary operator. The error message is clear, why don't you want to read it as it is ?

Comment: Are you running this code in your browser's console?

Answer (score 2):

The error is not because you used the ternary operator.

The message is telling you that JavaScript cannot find a function named "winBattle()" anywhere in your code - or at least, not within the current [scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).

As we will see in this demonstration, if you declare such a function, and make it return a simple boolean "true" value (just for example), then the error does not occur:

```js
var experiencePoints = winBattle() ? 10 : 1;
console.log(experiencePoints);

function winBattle()
{
  //I assume here you would have some logic to calculate the winner of the battle, and then return true or false depending on who won.
  return true;
}
```

You will need to check the rest of your code, and either

a) create the function, if it doesn't exist

or

b) make it accessible from the scope where you are calling it. If you need help with this task, you will have to show us the rest of your code.

Here is some background information:

I think you may have mistaken the `undefined` you're seeing as the *result* of executing the "experiencePoints" function. It is not. It is simply the result of *creating* that function via the console. The console always shows the result of the line you just created, which in this case is nothing, because you're just declaring a function, not running anything which produces output. If you included that function in a web page you would not see such a message. You have never actually run that function. If you did (by writing `experiencePoints();`) you would almost certainly see the same error relating to winBattle(), since at the time you run the function, winBattle() does not exist.

The difference between that and your ternary operator code is that this line of code is not within a function, and is therefore executed immediately.

Comment: Instead of `return true;` try just `return;` - should be more clear - upvoted :)

Comment: @Pilan that'll just make the result of the function false-y, so the ternary will return 1 instead of 10. Not sure what difference that makes to the example really, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: absolutely right, but he wanted an `undefined` result :D

Comment: @Pilan yes...that part of the request didn't really make any sense to me. Why would anyone want the function to return undefined? I can't see how that would be useful really, especially in the context shown. A two-way decision is supposed to be made based on the outcome of winBattle(), so that suggests to me that winBattle() ought to return a boolean. So while that may technically be the requested outcome, I'm going to suggest it's not a sensible one.

Comment: There's still quite a bit in the question that isn't really... resolved by this answer. For example, apparently their "working" function returns undefined, and that's what they want the ternary version to do. which... of course makes no sense.

Comment: It could be if the `winBattle()` just shows a message like "You won". Putting this into a `if` as `ternary` is kinda senseless indeed :)

Comment: @KevinB indeed. I'm going with the idea that returning undefined isn't a desirable outcome, and I'm trying to show a better way, as well as explaining the reason for the error message.

Comment: It would be *better* to instead wait for clarification to ensure we're actually answering the question the OP has.

Comment: @KevinB they are probably running this code in a browser's console. Which explains the `undefined` bit

Comment: @KevinB perhaps. But I don't know if you saw the original version of the question before it was tidied up? I'm not convinced that waiting for clarification is going to be overly productive, based on that. So I'm going with what I know and hoping it's helpful. I've also added an edit to explain my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The two are not the same: the `function experiencePoints` only executes when it is called, but you are not calling it. Instead you enter the function *definition* itself which does not return anything, and so you see `undefined` in the console.

The variable assignment with the ternary operator is executed on-the-spot (it is *not* a function definition), and so `winBattle` must exist at that very moment. Apparently it doesn't, and so you get an error. If you would just do this:

```
var a = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 10 : 1
```

You will not get an error, because `Math.random` is defined. Also you will see `undefined` in the console, which is normal for a statement, like `var`.

Coming back to the `function experiencePoints`: you may wonder why you don't get the same error about `winBattle` there. It is because the function is not *executed* yet.

Until you actually *call* it, you still have time to define `winBattle`. If however you decide to call it without first defining `winBattle`, you *will* get that same error.

Now you can of course use a ternary operator in a function -- that would be a fair comparison. You can choose between several syntaxes. Here are two:

```
function experiencePoints {
    return winBattle() ? 10 : 1;
}
```

or as arrow function with expression syntax:

```
var experiencePoints = () => winBattle() ? 10 : 1;
```

Again, here you would only get an error about `winBattle` when you *call* the function.

Comment: isnt `winBattle()` in the ternary calling the funtion? o_0

Comment: You said hes not calling it, but he is: `winBattle() ? 10 : 1;` or am i missing something?

Comment: You're missing something. I said that about the `function`, not about the assignment. The OP only *defines* the function `experiencePoints`, but does not execute it.

Comment: Aye, ok i see what you are saying. The part where the function declaration occurs is not executed. Got it :) - So maybe just a missing include?